# With Worksheets does not seem to change cell values on different sheets

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet, with-statement

I have macro which is written in the module. I have also userform to collect user input and populate certain cells on two different sheets on the same workbook.

In one of the subs in the Module I have declared:

```
Dim wsAssemblyBOM As Worksheet
Set wsAssemblyBOM = Worksheets("Assembly BOM")

Dim wsDocuments As Worksheet
Set wsDocuments = Worksheets("Documents")

HeaderInfoUserForm.Show
```

This will bring up my userform and everything seem to work as planned until we come to the OK button functionality:

```
Private Sub OK_Button_Click()

With wsAssemblyBOM
   Cells(2, 3) = Author.Value
   Cells(2, 5) = Title.Value
   Cells(2, 7) = SubCode.Value
   Cells(2, 6) = DateText.Value

   Version = BOMVersion.Value
End With

With wsDocuments
   Cells(2, 3) = Author.Value
   Cells(2, 5) = Title.Value
   Cells(2, 7) = SubCode.Value
   Cells(2, 6) = DateText.Value
End With

End Sub
```

This will only populate cells in the activesheet. I'm little bit confused here because all of the examples in the net suggest that this should work. I also tried to add dot in front of "Cells" but it only gives error.

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm also confused about when to start with a dot or not. For example:

```
With wsDocuments
   .Cells(2, 3) = Author.Value
   .Cells(2, 5) = Title.Value
   .Cells(2, 7) = SubCode.Value
   .Cells(2, 6) = DateText.Value
End With
```

This will give an error "Object Required". Cells is an object of worksheet but is error rather in that I'm trying to put value for .cells which is not actually the place for content of the cell? Without dot it is referring to the actual content of the cell? Just guessing here..

Many times dot is used in similar places. The logic is not clear to me. 
Example of working code:

```
 With FormatRange.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
```

Comment: About the `With`, it executes a series of statements that repeatedly refer to a single object or structure so that the statements can use a simplified syntax. Check [With...End With Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question, you say *In one of the subs in the Module I have declared:* and then you declare 2 variables for your Worksheets:

```
Dim wsAssemblyBOM As Worksheet
Set wsAssemblyBOM = Worksheets("Assembly BOM")

Dim wsDocuments As Worksheet
Set wsDocuments = Worksheets("Documents"
```

Those variables are available only in that sub. If you want to use them on several subs (like `Private Sub OK_Button_Click()`), you have to define your variables as Public in a module.

So in your module, at top, you must have:

```
Option Explicit

Public wsAssemblyBOM As Worksheet
Public wsDocuments As Worksheet
```

Something like this:

[image]

Now both variables can be used in any sub in your project, so your code should work. Make sure you assign them to the right worksheets. Once you have set them you don't need to do it again, unless you empty them with `Set MyVariable = Nothing`.

So your code should be something like:

```
Private Sub OK_Button_Click()

Set wsAssemblyBOM = Worksheets("Assembly BOM")
Set wsDocuments = Worksheets("Documents")

With wsAssemblyBOM
   .Cells(2, 3) = Author.Value
   .Cells(2, 5) = Title.Value
   .Cells(2, 7) = SubCode.Value
   .Cells(2, 6) = DateText.Value
   Version = BOMVersion.Value
End With

With wsDocuments
   .Cells(2, 3) = Author.Value
   .Cells(2, 5) = Title.Value
   .Cells(2, 7) = SubCode.Value
   .Cells(2, 6) = DateText.Value
End With

Set wsAssemblyBOM = Nothing
Set wsDocuments = Nothing

End Sub
```

Adapt it to your needs

Comment: Maybe you should check this too: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/3/5/explaining-private-vs-public-declarations

Answer (score 2):

You wrote,

```
With wsAssemblyBOM
   Cells(2, 3) = Author.Value
   Cells(2, 5) = Title.Value
   Cells(2, 7) = SubCode.Value
   Cells(2, 6) = DateText.Value

   Version = BOMVersion.Value
End With
```

It should have been,

```
With wsAssemblyBOM
   .Cells(2, 3) = Author.Value
   .Cells(2, 5) = Title.Value
   .Cells(2, 7) = SubCode.Value
   .Cells(2, 6) = DateText.Value

   Version = BOMVersion.Value
End With
```

Note the prefix `.` that passes the wsAssemblyBOM parent reference onto each .Cells. Assuming that wsAssemblyBOM and wsDocuments have been declared and Set to a worksheet and that they are available to the OK_Button_Click private sub then you should have no problems.

Your last example,

```
With FormatRange.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
```

... is the same as saying,

```
FormatRange.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
FormatRange.Borders(xlEdgeTop).ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
FormatRange.Borders(xlEdgeTop).TintAndShade = 0
FormatRange.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium
```

The verbose method is also slower as FormatRange.Borders(xlEdgeTop) has to be resolved four times.

Put [Option Explicit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyVrl.gif) at the top of every code sheet.